# How do you change the font color in the Unity panel?

Tags: unity, 11.04, fonts, panel

With my current (and favorite) theme the Unity panel is black text on a black background. Is there a way to set the font color in Unity or the theme somehow?

Comment: I know that this is an old thread, but since it hasn't been closed...
This issue persists in 12.04. Changing text[NORMAL] property changes other text as well, which is problematic. I am able to change it changing the theme and icons using myunity, but those changes are not persistent. They only seem to last for the session. Looks like a bug report was filed and resolved in 2010, but the problem is still present on my quite up-to-date machine. The dark text on a dark background makes unity unusable for me. Too bad, because I like it otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

The panel text uses the color defined by the theme's `text[NORMAL]` property. You'll likely find that in the file `/usr/share/themes/<theme>/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`.

Note, that this doesn't affect the home button and indicator icon color. For that you'd have to change the icon set used by your theme (in *Appearance Properties* → *Theme* tab).

Answer (score 0):

Use GTK Theme Preferences...

Code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shimmerproject/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gtk-theme-config
```

Also add your current panel background color when you change panel text color.
Install gcolor2 for the old style color picker to copy your panel color or look in your theme.