# How can I change the text color of the unity top panel?

Tags: unity, panel, text, globalmenu, colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you change the font color in the Unity panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33050/how-do-you-change-the-font-color-in-the-unity-panel)

I made a gtk theme and my panel black but the text color (globalmenu, clock) stays dark and I don't found out how to turn it readable. Where is the text color of the panel defined?

Thanks.